# is there an iOS counterpart of intent-filter in android?

Tags: javascript, android, swift

I am developing an app that sends a verification link via email. When the link in email is clicked, user should be prompted to open the iOS app if it is installed. Otherwise, it will direct to Safari browser for its website app counterpart. In android app, I was able to do this since there is the intent-filter feature in android development. Also, as much as possible, I am avoiding in iOS to redirect to the browser, and open the website, wait for it to load, then open the iOS app installed since it will be costly for the user to wait for the website to load. So the javascript workaround solution is my least option to do.

So I was wondering if there is an iOS counterpart of intent-filter. Or any workaround/implementation would be appreciated.

P.S. I am a newbie here in stackoverflow so go easy on me. thanks :))